# How to access a tab react-router-dom route from a listitem sidebar menu option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, listitem

I have set up Material-UI react-router tab navigation as shown here in this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-tab-react-router-bovd0?file=/src/index.js) example and all works fine.

My question is, I also have a left side-menu navigation setup that is using the Paperbase Material-UI template with the following code:

```
   {children.map(({ id: childId, icon, active, href }) => (
      <ListItem
        key={childId}
        button
        className={clsx(classes.item, active && classes.itemActiveItem)}
        component={Link}
        to={href}
      >
   ))}
```

Here `href` has the values: `"/books" and "/favorites"` which is what the material-UI tabs are using.

Using the above code, how can I direct a side-bar navigation menu click to go directly to this page that has both the `Books` and `Favourites` tabs and then also go into either the Books or Favourites components as if I clicked on either of these tabs myself?

I also need to ensure that the tab route path tab is active.